# Referencing objects with bounded types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

I'm trying to program a network of nodes, each node containing a list of references to another node. Node is an abstract class, so the lists will be referencing node-children.

The main abstract Node class - carries a list of input types (which itself is a list of nodes of that type). Since the class is abstract, I can only instanciate one of its children.

```
public abstract class Node {        
    ArrayList<Input<? extends Node>> inputs;

    public Node(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<Input<? extends Node>>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Input<? extends Node>> getInputNodes(){
        return(inputs);
    }

    public void killConnections() {
        for(Input<? extends Node> i:inputs){
            i.removefromInput(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract void something(); //not too important in this context....
}
```

I have different types of objects which act as an input. Different children of Node() may have different types of inputs. I therefore create a input class which works on a generic type. The input class, containing a list of references to other objects inheriting from Node, looks as follows:

```
public class Input<T extends Node> {
    ArrayList<T> inputs;

    public Input(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void removefromInput(T obj){
        inputs.remove(obj);
    }

    public void addToInput(T obj){
        inputs.add(obj);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getInputs(){
        return inputs;
    }       
}
```

Finally, my actual implemented node class. This is one of several children of Node, each child potentially has a different set of Input types which I define in the constructor.

```
public class ExplicitNode extends Node {  
    boolean active;

    public ExplicitNode(ExplicitNode inputNode){
        active = true;
        inputs.add(new Input<ExplicitNode>());
        inputs.get(0).addToInput(inputNode); //***Here i get an error
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        if(!inputs.get(0).getInputs().isEmpty()){           
            for(int i = 0; i< inputs.get(0).getInputs().size(); i++){
                //***Here i get an error too
                if(inputs.get(0).getInputs().get(i).active){ . 
                //do something....,
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

I get following error:

> The method addToInput(capture#1-of ? extends Node) in the type
>   Input is not applicable for the
>   arguments (ExplicitNode)

The second error (The "active" field cannot be resolved) also confuses me - I instanciated an input of type `<ExplicitNode>`, hence the input's arrayList should also return objects of type `ExplicitNode` containing the "active" field??

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ` the input's arrayList should also return objects of type ExplicitNode` - no, because you're not parameterising the `ArrayList` as such.

Comment: I thought that if I have "Input<T extends Node>" in the class header that the T inside "ArrayList<T> inputs" in the body is already understood as inheriting from Node. So that if I create input<ExplicitNode>, the ArrayList will hence contain objects of type ExplicitNode.

Answer (score 0):

In the abstract Node you have inputs declared as

```
ArrayList<Input<? extends Node>>
```

which means that it does not gurantee that inputs will always have ExplicitNode type.

You need to change your Node to be generic as well, like this:

```
    public static abstract class Node< T extends Node<T> > {        
    ArrayList< Input<T> > inputs;

    public Node(){
        inputs = new ArrayList< Input<T> >();
    }

    public ArrayList< Input<T> > getInputNodes(){
        return inputs;
    }

    public void killConnections() {
        for(Input<T> i:inputs){
            i.removefromInput( getThis() );
        }
    }

    protected abstract T getThis();

    public abstract void something(); //not too important in this context....
}

public static class Input< T extends Node<T> > {
    ArrayList<T> inputs;

    public Input(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void removefromInput(T obj){
        inputs.remove(obj);
    }

    public void addToInput(T obj){
        inputs.add(obj);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getInputs(){
        return inputs;
    }       
}

public static class ExplicitNode extends Node<ExplicitNode> {  
    boolean active;

    public ExplicitNode(ExplicitNode inputNode){
        active = true;
        inputs.add(new Input<ExplicitNode>());
        inputs.get(0).addToInput(inputNode); //***Here i get an error
    }

    protected ExplicitNode getThis(){
        return this;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        if(!inputs.get(0).getInputs().isEmpty()){           
            for(int i = 0; i< inputs.get(0).getInputs().size(); i++){
                //***Here i get an error too
                if(inputs.get(0).getInputs().get(i).active){ 
                //do something....,
            }           
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void something() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Or here is another approach without using generic abstract class. Personally I still prefer to use generic abstract class:

```
public static abstract class Node {        

    public abstract ArrayList< ? extends Input<? extends Node> > getInputNodes();

    public void killConnections() {
        for( Input<? extends Node> i : getInputNodes() ){
            i.removefromInput(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract void something(); //not too important in this context....
}

public static class Input<T extends Node> {
    ArrayList<T> inputs;

    public Input(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void removefromInput(Object obj){
        inputs.remove(obj);
    }

    public void addToInput(T obj){
        inputs.add(obj);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getInputs(){
        return inputs;
    }       
}


public static class ExplicitNode extends Node {  
    ArrayList< Input<ExplicitNode> > inputs = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean active;

    public ExplicitNode(ExplicitNode inputNode){
        active = true;
        inputs.add( new Input<ExplicitNode>() );
        inputs.get(0).addToInput(inputNode); 
    }

    public ArrayList< ? extends Input<? extends Node> > getInputNodes(){
        return  inputs;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        if ( !inputs.get(0).getInputs().isEmpty() ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.get(0).getInputs().size(); i++) {
                if (inputs.get(0).getInputs().get(i).active) {
                    // do something....,
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void something() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
}
```

Comment: That was quick, thx for the comment..! Works almost - except killConnections() which you omitted in your answer will not work for Input<T>.

Comment: Also, while I assume generics will allow to work around my problem - I wonder if this could not be solved by designing some smarter form of inheritance scheme? Adding all these subtypes doesn't seem to be too clean.

Comment: I updated with the code including killConnections. You can try to use casts instead of generics or not use inputs field in the abstract class. 
I will think about a different approach post it if I find one.

Comment: Casts are bad. Avoid them.

Comment: Indeed, the whole reason why I ran into this problem was by trying to avoid casting of any kind. I tried to avoid generics as well, and while I have a version where I completely avoid generics, it again needs casts to work...

Comment: @Tsolak Petrosian, just only saw your version without the generic abstract class - I personally prefer that one as it is more readable. Is there a specific reason for you preferring a generic abstract class? Because simply inheriting children from Node without self-referring generics makes intuitive sense to me. Then again, I'm still catching up on inheritance and generics, there seems to be a lot to learn...

Comment: 1) The first approach clearly defines the contract that parent class and "getInputNodes" will only contain one type of sub class. Using generics is not only about avoiding casts but about defining contract. 
<br/>
2) inputs can be created in parent class instead of subclass.
<br/>
3) The "removefromInput" wont have to take Object type but actual subclass type.

Answer (score 0):

So I've added here a version without Generics, but on the other hand relying on Casting once actual objects are instanced, which I think is significantly worse than using generics:

```
public abstract class Node {        
    ArrayList<Input> inputs;

    public Node(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<Input>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Input> getInputNodes(){
        return(inputs);
    }

    public void killConnections() {
        for(Input i:inputs){
            i.removefromInput(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract void something(); //not too important in this context....
}

public class Input {
    ArrayList<Node> inputs;

    public Input(){
        inputs = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public void removefromInput(Node obj){
        inputs.remove(obj);
    }

    public void addToInput(Node obj){
        inputs.add(obj);
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getInputs(){
        return inputs;
    }       
}

public class ExplicitNode extends Node {  
    boolean active;

    public ExplicitNode(ExplicitNode inputNode){
        active = true;
        inputs.add(new Input());
        inputs.get(0).addToInput(inputNode);
    }

    //Note the ugly cast
    public void someMethod() {
        if(!inputs.get(0).getInputs().isEmpty()){  
            for(int i = 0; i< inputs.get(0).getInputs().size(); i++){
                Node node = inputs.get(0).getInputs().get(i);
                if(node instanceof ExplicitNode){
                    ExplicitNode explicitNode = (ExplicitNode)node;
                    if(explicitNode.active){
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

I still got a hunch that a smarter inheritance setup might actually work without relying on the generics, but can't get my mind around it...